# Devise - ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, devise

I want the user to have a own page, /users/52. So I did add a new controller o make this happen, the controller is user_controller.rb.
But now, the other functionalities dosen't work.

When I have routes like below. The /users/sign_in doesn't work. 
But the /users/1 does work.

```
#Users/show!!!
  match 'users/:id' => 'users#show', via: :get
  # or 
  get 'users/:id' => 'users#show'
  # or
  resources :users

  devise_for :users, controllers: {
          sessions: 'users/sessions'
  }
```

When I use routes like below. The /users/1 dosen't work but the users/sign_in work.

```html
  

  devise_for :users, controllers: {
          sessions: 'users/sessions'
  }
```

```html
class UsersController < ApplicationController

#def show
# @user = User.friendly.find(params[:id])
# @links = Link.all.where(user_id: @user).publish
#end

def index
 @users = User.all
end

def show

 @user = User.friendly.find(params[:id])
 @links = Link.all.where(user_id: @user).publish
end

def new
 
end



end
```

Comment: Did you create the user you are trying to sign in with, the error means something is not found in the database (most likely the user)

Comment: The user is created. Because I can login to the website if I remove these lines: match 'users/:id' => 'users#show', via: :get
  # or 
  get 'users/:id' => 'users#show'
  # or
  resources :users

Comment: Have you tried with `resources :users, only: [:show]`? I'm afraid the other options won't work because the devise action will be interpreted as an ID (i.e. in `/users/sign_in`, new will be passed to your UsersController as `id: 'sign_in'`). Also, unless you limit `resources` to `:show`, it could mask devise's routes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just need to move the `resources :users` (or the other variants you have) AFTER the devise declaration. Mappings that come first have priority in the routes file, so all get requests of type 'users/anything` will match your users#show action and never get to the devise controllers. Lets go through an example:

When a user tries to visit `users/sign_in`, rails starts matching the path with the mappings in your routes file, from top to bottom, and when it reaches `users/:id`, it assumes 'sign_in' is meant as value for `:id`(since the path structure matches), so it chooses the `users#show` action and if you look at the params in the show action, you will see that `id` has been giver the value 'sign_in'.

If you put the `users/:id` mapping after the `devise_for` block, then input paths will first be matched to more strict mappings (e.g. only path `users/sign_in` would match a mapping of `users/sign_in`) and then the wider `users/:id`

So, in short:

```
devise_for :users, controllers: {
      sessions: 'users/sessions'
}
resources :users
```

Will work.

Answer (score 0):

What's happening is that when requesting "users/sing_in" your controller is looking for a record with id "sign_in", such record doesn't exist, hence the activerecord not found error.

You should place get 'users/:id' => 'users#show' **after** "devise_for" block, and *not before*.